# Need to track user login and logout event by using event listener, but login and logout event-listener is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

We are using OKTA for Oauth2 token based authentication. Below are steps to make connection.

```
application.properties:
oktaOrgUrl=https://dev-1111.okta.com
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-1111.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=/implicit/callback
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Application works properly, but we had to track user login and logout events.

Written implementation classes of LogoutSuccessHandler for logout,

```
@Component
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Authentication arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
}
```

Configured login and logout event listener in WebSecurityConfig.java

```
http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Client().and().oauth2Login().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
```

Problem is that, login and logout event-listener is not working and not listening this event.

Comment: It is not clear you have autowired LogoutSuccessHandler or not and the configuration code info you provided is not complete

Comment: Which version of Spring-Boot and the Okta-Spring-Boot-Starter are you using?

Comment: When you POST to `/logout`, is the session removed?

Comment: @BrianDemers session is removed on /logout. Spring-boot (2.1.1.RELEASE) and okta-spring-boot-starter (1.2.1) is used.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi only sample reference code is attached, tried lot of things, but login and logout event listener are not calling.

Comment: @Ganan can you open an issue in https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues. I’ll take a look at it

Comment: @BrianDemers I opened issue in github.com/okta, appreciate for your input.